# Why does the longest prefix which is also suffix calculation part in the KMP have a time complexity of O(n) and not O(n^2)?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was going through the code of KMP when I noticed the Longest Prefix which is also suffix calculation part of KMP. Here is how it goes,

```
void computeLPSArray(char* pat, int M, int* lps) 
{ 
    int len = 0; 

    lps[0] = 0;  

    int i = 1; 
    while (i < M) { 
       if (pat[i] == pat[len]) { 
          len++; 
          lps[i] = len; 
          i++; 
       } 
       else 
       { 
          if (len != 0) { 
              len = lps[len - 1]; //<----I am referring to this part

          } 
          else 
          { 
              lps[i] = 0; 
              i++; 
          } 
      } 
  } 
}
```

Now the part where I got confused was the one which I have shown in comments in the above code. Now we do know that when a code contains a loop like the following

```
int a[m];
memset(a, 0, sizeof(a));
for(int i = 0; i<m; i++){
   for(int j = i; j>=0; j--){
       a[j] = a[j]*2;//This inner loop is causing the same cells in the 1 
                     //dimensional array to be visited more than once. 
   }
}
```

The complexity comes out to be O(m*m). 
Similarly if we write the above LPS computation in the following format

```
while(i<M){
   if{....}
   else{
      if(len != 0){
          //doesn't this part cause the code to again go back a few elements
          //in the LPS array the same way as the inner loop in my above 
          //written nested for loop does? Shouldn't that mean the same cell
          //in the array is getting visited more than once and hence the 
          //complexity should increase to O(M^2)?
      }
   }

}
```

It might be that the way I think complexities are calculated is wrong. So please clarify.

Comment: Maybe you want to tell us what "KMP" is.

Comment: @jesper agreed, but google kmp algorithm finds it.  String searching.

Answer (score 1):

If expressions do not take time that grows with len.

Len is an integer.  Reading it takes O(1) time.

Array indexing is O(1).

Visiting something more than once does not mean you are higher O notation wise.  Only if the visit count grows faster than kn for some k.

Answer (score 0):

If you carefully analyze the algorithm of creating prefix table, you may notice that the total number of rollbacked positions could be `m` at most, so the upper bound for total number of iterations is `2*m` which yields `O(m)`

Value of `len` grows alongside the main iterator `i` and whenever there is a mismatch, `len` drops back to zero value but this "drop" cannot exceed the interval passed by the main iterator `i` since the start of match.

For example,  let's say, the main iterator `i` started matching with `len` at position 5 and mismatched at position 20.
So,

```
LPS[5]=1  
LPS[6]=2  
...  
LPS[19]=15
```

At the moment of mismatch, `len` has a value of 15. Hence it may rollback at most 15 positions down to zero, which is equivalent to the interval passed by `i` while matching.  In other words, on every mismatch, `len` travels back no more than `i` has traveled forward since the start of match